# UITabBarController - don't show the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

I'm creating an iPhone app with UITabBarController.
What I want to achieve is that when I tap some items on tabbar I don't want them to activate new view, instead of it I want them to run some functionality in the current view.
For example I have a view with map active and when I click some item on tabbar I want it to locate the current position on the map.
I don't know if using UITabBarController is the best solution for this. I'll also want 1 item to swap between 2 views (map / list).
Would it be better to use some kind of ToolBar on bottom or anything completely different?
I don't think there is any code needed, but I've got a UITabBarViewController app created and I created a UITabBarControllerDelegate like this:

```
@interface MainTabBarControllerDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

and

```
@implementation MainTabBarControllerDelegate

@synthesize tabBarController, window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

}

@end
```

But I don't know how to achieve the functionality.
Thanks.

Comment: If you wish to perform some action like you said which is performed in the same controller then using a UITabBarViewController is not a preferred option. You can use simple buttons which can give you an illusion of a tabBar instead.

Comment: It would be highly unusual&confuse the crap out of the potential users of your app (even may be against Apple's HIG, but not sure). If you want to perform specific task inside your current view, then either use UIToolbar or UISegmentedControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you don't need a `UITabBarController` for this. A `UIToolbar` or your own custom `UIView` would be enough. But if you want to use `UITabBarController`, you'll have to override its usual functioning:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
return NO; //do not select any view controller here
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
  // find which tab was tapped here and handle the map's current position 
  // location operation accordingly
}
```

You can also refer to [this link](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/detect-taps-on-uitabbarcontroller-and-determining-class-type.html) for more tips...

Comment: Not that I want to use it, it was just my first idea and it seemed wrong to override the functionality totally for each item (or most of them), I'll try to check the UIToolbar, thanks :).